# Copying 1 variable of 1 type to another variable of another type in C

Tags: c

I had an interview yesterday where they had asked me to write a function which accepts 3 arguments,1 source , 1 destination and other the length and this function should copy the value from source to destination based on the length parameter and the types of source and destination could be different.

Can someone please help me write a generic function ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Sounds like memcpy: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean `memcpy` (or `memmove`)? :P

A naive implementation (using bytes):

```
int my_memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t len)
{
    if (dest == NULL || src == NULL || src == dest) return -1;
    if (len == 0) return 0;

    char *dest_bytes = dest;
    const char *src_bytes = src;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        dest_bytes[i] = src_bytes[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

One can optimise using `uint64_t` pointers (taking care of the remainder with a `char *`) and loop unrolling to copy more data each iteration of the for loop.